# What is the action for a rollover in Rails Stimulus

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, openlayers, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I have a map (geographic) with lines drawn from one location to another. When rollover that line the information about the end points should be displayed. I've got the map and line drawing in a `connect` action in a Rails Stimulus controller and want to implement the rollover display.

In JavaScript the `pointermove` event when it crosses certain coordinates as follows:

```
const popoverTextElement = document.getElementById('popover-text'); // an empty div on people>show
const popoverTextLayer = new Overlay({ // an OpenLayers function
  element : popoverTextElement,
})
map.addOverlay(popoverTextLayer); // empty at start, but establishes the layer

map.on('pointermove', function(evt){
  let featureInfo = '';
  let isFeatureAtPixel = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel); // OpenLayers function. ie, is a feature where we are
  if (isFeatureAtPixel) {
    let featureAtPixel = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel);
     for (var i = 0; i <= featureAtPixel.length - 1; i++) {
      featureInfo = featureInfo + featureAtPixel[i].get('popover_people');
    }
    popoverTextLayer.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    popoverTextElement.innerHTML = featureInfo; // all
    map.getViewport().style.cursor = 'pointer' // the hand
  } else {
    popoverTextLayer.setPosition(undefined); // otherwise text remains after leaving
    map.getViewport().style.cursor = ''; // change back to arrow which is default
  }
});
```

For starters, can the line be detected in Stimulus?